# NSAttributedString with embedded images

Tags: nsattributedstring

Does anybody know of any code out there that would allow me to read RTF with images in `NSAttributedString`?

Yes I know that there is RTFD format and initWithRTF methods... But implementation of initWithRTF skips \pict tags so when I transfers RTF from Windows (MS Office) to osx and try to open it with NSTextView I don't see embedded images. Also I tryed it with librtf and I have some sussesfull results but in my opnion its ugly solution

Answer (score 0):

Neither QuickLook nor TextEdit can deal with inline attachments, so I'm pretty sure Cocoa doesn't support them. librtf is your best bet.